# Pass data between two screens with React Native and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm trying to pass data between two different screens

Here is the data:

```js
const [arrange, setArrange] = useState(false); // the clubs arrange state
```

The state is updating the home screen and arranging it differently based on the 'arrange' value (if true, one way, if false another).
I want to update the `arrange` value on the second screen and send it back to the home screen and see the change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the call-back function to pass to the next screen
like 
`this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen2',{onBackCallBack:this. onBackCallBack})`

this function will be in your Screen 1 and you can do any thing when you back from Screen2
`onBackCallBack=()=>{}`

while you getting back from Screen 2 you have called this prop like 
`this.props.navigation.state.params.onBackCallBack()`